# restrict url access in JSP

Tags: jsp, url

I have a site that uses forms and validates fields and redirects to another pages etc, but I need to know how to keep any user from accessing a page directly with the URL and it gets redirected to the login form...

I've seen this, but I don't know how to call it. :S

I think it's with session variables, and that I should check for a session variable in the top of the page that I want to restrict.

I am using JSP in building my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this declaratively with security constraints in the deployment descriptor.

Essentially, you say 'this set of resources is only accessible by users in a given set of rules using a given set of HTTP methods', as follows:

Resources behind URLs /secured/* are only accessible to authenticated users in the 'admin' role.

```
<web-app...>
  <security-constraint>

    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
      <description>Secured pages</description>
      <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
      <description>Administrative users</description>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

  </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

It requires some setup - security realms etc, login form configuration, but it means that your security setup is not done programmatically, instead it is in a tool-supported and abstracted, declarative way. This helps keep your code clean and focussed.

Here's the relevant part of the [Sun Educational material for Java EE 5](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html). It's a relatively complex and potentially very important topic so I suggest you have a good read through of the material there.

Answer (score 2):

Java EE tutorial has a section dedicated to [securing web applications](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bncas.html).

That's what you need to do - you'll be able to declare your security constraints in your webapp descriptor (`web.xml`). [Here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bnccm) is an example of how to secure a particular URL

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use a filter that catches all requests and forwards to the correct path as appropriate. It would take more work than security constraints but you could have more control over processing.

Using security constraints is certainly a good simple solution, though.